ObservedObject not reacting to @Published data change
Im setting new data of @Published property from async contex
func prePopulate(screen: Screen, completion: @escaping () -> Void) async {
    let data = await ClientManager.fetchMember(memberId: memberId)
    let memberData = MemberData(memberInfo: data)
    let screenData = MemberDetailsScreenData(memberData: memberData, screenName: "member_details_screen")
    let memberPersonalData = MemberPersonalDetailsComponentData(responseData: memberData)
    let memberTrainingData = MemberTrainingDetailsComponentData(responseData: memberData)

    await MainActor.run{
        screen.component(of: MemberPersonalDetailsComponent.self)?.populate(data: memberPersonalData)
        screen.component(of: MemberTrainingDetailsSwiftUIWrapperComponent.self)?.populate(data: memberTrainingData)
    }
    screen.populate(data: screenData)
    
    completion()
}

populate() is setting data inside UIHostingController subclass
 class DetailsSectionSwiftUIWrapper: UIHostingController<DetailsSectionViews<MemberDetailsSection>> {

@Published var viewData: ComponentData = MemberTrainingDetailsComponentData(responseData: nil)

convenience init(parent: ContainerComponent?) {
    let rootView = DetailsSectionViews<MemberDetailsSection>(data: MemberTrainingDetailsComponentData(responseData: nil), parentComponent: parent!)
    self.init(rootView: rootView)
}

// Magic
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    rootView.data = viewData
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

func setData(data: ComponentData?) {
    guard let data = data else {return}
    self.viewData = data
}

@Published var viewData changes are applied to property and I can check that but @ObseervedObject which is data of DetailSectionViews does not respond to applied changes
struct DetailsSectionViews<Builder: DetailsSectionListBuilder>: View {
@ObservedObject var data: ComponentData
let parentComponent: ContainerComponent
// let function: () -> Void

var body: some View{...

Even if I try with objectWillChange breakpoint will not be triggered.
What do you think about my code does it seem to be written properly?

To use ObservableObject class in SwiftUI, see this link  Monitoring data it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app.

Have you turned on strict concurrency? If not you probably should. prePopulate Goes against the basic concepts of the new concurrency. What is the point of that completion handler?
